# Bootstrap TabPanel Tab - Disable Page Scrolling To Element's ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My TabPanel Tab's title consists of two things:

1. checkbox
2. title of the tab

To show tabs, I use jQuery code:

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

With this kind of a code the page scrolls to each div every time I click on a tab. If I add jQuery code line `e.preventDefault();` before `$(this).tab('show');` line which disables the scrolling, then comes the second problem - checkboxes doesn't check/uncheck any more.

Any ideas, how to escape from both problems?

Example with scrolling problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/717/

Example with checkbox checking/unchecking problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/718/

Comment: what is scrolling problem. i couldn't find it .can you explain more please

Comment: Try to click on any tab. As You can see - the page scrolls down everytime You click on any tab. I don't want that page scrolls to the anchor ids because it's quite annoying that everytime I click on a tab the page is doing the scroll thing to the exact id.

Comment: Any help on this please? No one can solve this?

Comment: chk this. i have updated your html too . if you find it feasible then say
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/K9LpL/720/

Comment: Your checkboxes are buggy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT - Roman's answer below is a better solution than this one.**

Using `preventDefault()` you can add code to manually toggle the checkboxes.

```
var checked = $(this).find('input').prop('checked');
$(this).find('input').prop('checked', !checked);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/722/)

Edit:

I decided to approach this the other way. Do not use `preventDefault()` and instead, fix the scrolling issue. I was able to do this with `$(window).scrollTop(0)` and a very, very small delay/timeout.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).scrollTop();

    $(this).tab('show');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).scrollTop(scrollHeight );
    }, 5);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/726/)

Comment: This could be a half of the solution. I would like that checkboxes work also when clicked on the checkbox only.

Comment: I want that the checkboxes check and uncheck when the click is only on the checkbox. I don't want that checkboxes check and uncheck when I click on the title name of tab.

Comment: @TomsBugna I'll see if I can find a workaround, but the problem is that when you click the checkbox, the event for the anchor tag is firing. This makes it difficult to get a click event on the checkbox itself.

Comment: yeah, I also noticed this one. I also tried to make a workaround with it, but I failed. But I feel that somewhere near is the solution for this one, but still need to fight and try some other workarounds. I would really appreciate it if You could find out the solution for this.

Comment: @TomsBugna I'm not having any luck so far. It doesn't look like a checkbox will work inside of an anchor tag. We might have to switch around your HTML to get what you want to work. I'll get back to you if I can find a good solution.

Comment: Hmm.. I even don't have any idea, how could we rebuild the HTML for this and get the result I needed. I will also try to change something in HTML code to see if that helps.

Comment: @TomsBugna I found a working solution without using `preventDefault()`. Please see the edit in my answer, as well as the Demo.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. I updated it a little bit so that the page won't run everytime to the 0px height of the content, but to the place before clicked. It will be a little bit less annoying to users. :)

Answer (score 63):

You can use
`<a data-target="#home">`
instead of `<a href="#home">`

See a jsfiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RPSmedia/K9LpL/1154/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Not even one line of code!

Comment: @IanBrindley Yes, this is definitely a better solution than mine. I suppose since it was more than a year later the OP never came back to bother with it.

Comment: Amazing Answer, wish i had option to give double thumbs up !!

Comment: Even as of Bootstrap 4 in 2020, this is still the best answer to this issue!

Answer (score 9):

I fixed this by adding e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to the event handler:

```
$('.nav-tabs li a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

edit: fixed class selector as per comment.

Comment: you forgot . in your selecto .nav-tabs

Comment: Thanks, Joel! can't believe I didn't notice that typo before.

Answer (score 1):

My method (used on `nav-pills` but you can replace `pill` to `tab` easily, modified @Tricky12's answer a little because I didn't like `setTimeout` when using a faded tab switch:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // buffer the last scroll position
    var lastScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        location.replace($(e.target).attr("href"));
        // revert back to last scroll position
        $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollPosition);
    });

    // switch to the currently selected tab when loading the page
    $('.nav-pills a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').tab("show");

    $('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on("click", function(e){
        // buffer the scroll position again
        lastScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        // show the tab
        $(this).tab('show');
        // prevent default actions
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Note**: coded on Bootstrap 4.3 but I suppose it'll work on older versions too.